# Pass REQUEST_URI from Apache to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, cgi, request-uri

We currently migrate from one environment to another and have to, instead of just an Apache, an Apache and a Tomcat to redirect the user to the correct instance on the server. In some applications we use the REQUEST_URI CGI Environment Variable to gather information. When I request all CGI Environment Variables in the system with just the Apache, i recieve the REQUEST_URI perfectly, but on the new system, with the Tomcat, it won't come up. Does someone have an idea how I can pass the variable from the Apache to the Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called an Apache Tomcat connector. It "just" needs to be configured by the handy guide on this official tomcat page: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html